# SQL logger file for messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, logging

I am executing couple of update and append scripts on my sql server, and the results sql shows like

```
(73558 row(s) affected)
```

or

```
successfully column created
```

so, any messages which pop up, after an operation, how can I save them to a log/ text file. Like I do in python. It will be really helpful to see my scripts progress when I set up them on task scheduler for running automatically. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

- Run your scripts through sqlcmd and redirect output to a file.
- Modify your scripts to write diagnostic messages after each statement to a log table.

Comment: Pls write a sample query, It will be really helpful

Comment: E-e-er... Encapsulate each statement in `TRY ... CATCH` block and `INSERT INTO [LogTable] (StatementId, ErrorMessage) VALUES 'Current Statement ID', ERROR_MESSAGE();`. Right after each statement SQL / DML statement: `INSERT INTO [LogTable] (StatementId, RowsAffected) VALUES 'Current Statement ID', @@ROWCOUNT;`. Of cause, you would need this `[LogTable]`, presumably with auto-populated date column etc. That's really ugly, but that's the only way from inside SQL-script I know. Alternatively run the scripts through sqlcmd on Windows Scheduler rather than SQL Agent.